# How to send a message to the iframe whose src has been changed

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am working on an html page which hosts a iframe and will change depending upon situation. The iframe src change is easily accomplished but sending message to that iframe (through iframe.contentWindow.postMessage) isn't happening. I did some test run and saw that message being displayed on previous iframe.

After that I thought of using asynchronus approach (tries async/await and promise also) thinking my problem has to be because of that but the problem still persisted.

I am working with vanilla js and below is simplified snippet of codes.

Main index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
   <iframe id="bodyChange" src="pubMode.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   <script src="../script/popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, below are html pages which have to be in iframe.

pubMode.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button id="settingBtn">Setting</button>
    <button id="privMode">Private Mode</button>

    <div id="container"></div>
   <script src="../script/frame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

setting.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div id="settingPage"></div>

    <script src="../script/setting.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

privMode.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <button id="settingBtn">Setting</button>
    <button id="pubMode">Public Mode</button>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="../script/frame.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Js script.

frame.js

```
var frame = {
init: function(){
    //msg sender
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        var message = JSON.stringify({
            id: event.target.id
        });
        window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
    });

    //msg reciever
    window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e.data;
    });
   
}}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', frame.init);
```

popup.js

```
class popup{
   iframeMap = {
    'settingBtn': 'setting.html',
    'privMode': 'privMode.html',
    'pubMode': 'pubMode.html',
    'editBtn': 'edit.html'
   }

  constructor(){
    window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
            let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, error) => {
                let frameObj = document.getElementById('bodyChange');
                frameObj.src = this.iframeMap[data.id];

                resolve(frameObj);
            }); 
           
            myPromise.then(frameObj => {
                console.log(frameObj.src);
                frameObj.contentWindow.postMessage(response, '*');
            });
           }
         });
       }
    }

   var obj = new popup();
```

Comment: What is `.iframeMap`?

Comment: iframeMap is a dictionary containing the address of different iframe. When button is for changing iframe it's id is send to popup.js and that id is mapped to the html page it has to switch to. Had forgotten adding it, edited it you can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `iframe.onload` event handler in your `popup.js`.

**popup.js**

```js
class popup {
  iframeMap = {
    settingBtn: "setting.html",
    privMode: "privMode.html",
    pubMode: "pubMode.html",
    editBtn: "edit.html"
  };
  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      let frameObj = document.getElementById("bodyChange");
      frameObj.src = this.iframeMap[data.id];
      console.log(frameObj.src);
      frameObj.onload = () => {
        // TODO: replace frameObj.src with response
        frameObj.contentWindow.postMessage(frameObj.src, "*");
      };
    });
  }
}

var obj = new popup();
```

I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-zeh-l23x7d) that demonstrate it.